# Does order matter in an MLA7 header

Tags: academic-writing, mla

In *A Pocket Style Manual, 7th ed.*, it says that, although MLA doesn't require a title page, you need to have a header with you name, instructor's name, course title, and the date.

> **Title and identification**   MLA does not require a title page. On the first page of your paper, place your name, your instructor's name, the course title, and the date on separate lines against the left margin. Then center your title.

(p. 167)

In my paper currently, I have

> [My Name]
>
> [Instructor's Name]
>
> [Course Number]
>
> [Date]

Does the order matter?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the order matters.  Yes, I do believe it's trivial, but I've been enforced on that particular order, and I've encouraged others to stick to the order.  All in all, though, it honestly depends on the temperament of the teacher or professor in question.  I certainly wouldn't deduct major points for the heading being slightly out of order, but others are sticklers.

I'm also assuming you're asking here because you need to turn in an assignment for a class.  Please correct me if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's for an assignment, but I'm mainly just curious.  I'm pretty sure that my teacher won't care between that and the other format I've seen, which switches around the course number and instructor's name.  Do you have any sources by chance other than simply experience (which is fine)?

Comment: The Purdue owl is a great resource for academic styles such as MLA.  Here is a sample paper: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/13/